# industrial core

Tags: rosinstall, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Community,
i'm a beginner.
I need this packege: [industrial_core](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core).

but sudo apt-get install industrial_core
dont work. what should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126736/industrial-core/) by [sonyfuchs](https://answers.ros.org/users/11651/sonyfuchs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link doesn't work. Do you have the correct sources? It should be

```
ros-groovy-industrial-core
```

or

```
ros-hydro-industrial-core
```

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonyfuchs](https://answers.ros.org/users/11651/sonyfuchs/) on 2014-02-06**:
thank you very much :D